# Relocate node with value in XML if not exists in mssql

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've got table in mssql, and one column of it contains XML. Most of XML in this column looks like this:

```
<AuthenticationParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <MyParams>
        <Username>AmaryllisAPITest</Username>
        <ApplicationId>3</ApplicationId>
    </MyParams>
    <AlsoParams>
        <AuthBehavior>Authorization</AuthBehavior>
        <SecretKey>MVHXAQA5kF4Ab9siV4vPA4aVPn1EKhbqIBrpCZx2Hg</SecretKey>
    </AlsoParams>
</AuthenticationParams>
```

I want to relocate **AuthBehavior** node right after **AuthenticationParams** node, so it will look like this:

```
<AuthenticationParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AuthBehavior>Authorization</AuthBehavior>
    <MyParams>
        <Username>AmaryllisAPITest</Username>
        <ApplicationId>3</ApplicationId>
    </MyParams>
    <AlsoParams>
        <SecretKey>MVHXAQA5kF4Ab9siV4vPA4aVPn1EKhbqIBrpCZx2Hg</SecretKey>
    </AlsoParams>
</AuthenticationParams>
```

How can I do that? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<AuthenticationParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <MyParams>
        <Username>AmaryllisAPITest</Username>
        <ApplicationId>3</ApplicationId>
    </MyParams>
    <AlsoParams>
        <AuthBehavior>Authorization</AuthBehavior>
        <SecretKey>MVHXAQA5kF4Ab9siV4vPA4aVPn1EKhbqIBrpCZx2Hg</SecretKey>
    </AlsoParams>
</AuthenticationParams>';
DECLARE @temp TABLE (XmlData xml);
INSERT @temp VALUES (@xml);

UPDATE t
    SET XmlData.modify('insert /AuthenticationParams/AlsoParams/AuthBehavior
            as first
            into (/AuthenticationParams)[1]')
    FROM @temp t;

UPDATE t
    SET XmlData.modify('delete /AuthenticationParams/AlsoParams/AuthBehavior')
    FROM @temp t;

SELECT * FROM @temp;
```